# how to get all values from Looping a dynamic List in c#?

Tags: c#, wpf, for-loop, dynamic

i have a dynamic List like this :

```
dynamic[,] Tablevalues = {
                         { 1       ,"FirstName"        , 11111111111111 },
                         { 2       ,"SecondName"       , 22222222222222 }, 
                         { 3       ,"ThirdName"        , 33333333333333 }
                         };
```

and i want to loop it so i can add it later in my .Mdf DataBase , and what i tried so far is :

```
for (int i=0; i<Tablevalues.Length; i++){

      // ----- output just for test ------
      MessageBox.Show(  Tablevalues[i, i].ToString()  );             
      }
```

but the result of "`Tablevalues[i, i]`" only show me :

```
1  ,           ,   
   ,SecondName , 
   ,           ,33333333333333
```

- so how to output all the Values ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < Tablevalues.Length; i++) {
    MessageBox.Show(Tablevalues[i, i].ToString());
}
```

You only have one loop variable, so you're only looping from `0, 0`, `1, 1`... up to `Length - 1, Length - 1` (i.e. the diagonal.)

Use two `for`-loops, along with `GetLength(dimension)` to get the rows/columns.

Something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Tablevalues.GetLength(0); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < Tablevalues.GetLength(1); j++) {
        MessageBox.Show(Tablevalues[i, j].ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you , the code works perfect and the description was good to understand the reasons behind :)

Answer (score 1):

Because you need two `for` for 2d array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Tablevalues.GetLength(0); i++)
{
  for (int j = 0; j < Tablevalues.GetLength(1); j++)
  {
    MessageBox.Show(Tablevalues[i, j].ToString());
  }
}
```